# Multiple ActiveRecord Queries in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I want to do the following:

```
//set up insert....
$this->db->insert('property');
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
//some stuff
//set up get
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$id = $this->db->get();
```

This does not work.  It would appear the insert is not being executed before the get - the get is returning zero rows.  The insert does (eventually) work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This is obviously not ideal (inserting and then reading), but it simplifies my code greatly.  There's probably a better way, but I don't have the energy to fix it.  What's more irritating now is my lack of understanding as to why the above doesn't work.

Comment: You may want check your database content - and when it's wrong, call `$this->db->last_query()` - will return the latest query, so you can see your dinamically created queries.

Comment: Why does inserting and then reading simplify code?  If you're inserting a row, why do you need to then read it?  Don't you already have the data that you're inserting?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an argument - `insert()` takes two:

1. A table name
2. An array or object containing columns and values

[From the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#insert):

```
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'date' => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data); 

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date')
```

So, you need to supply `insert()` with the necessary data by including an array or object as the second argument.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you can use the `$this->db->set()` method for setting values, as explained in [Rocket's more comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166926/30433), which also points out you need to specify a table when selecting data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give `insert` some data to insert.

With either the `set` method:

```
$this->db->set('name', 'Eric');
$this->db->insert('property');
```

or by passing an array as the 2nd parameter:

```
$this->db->insert('property', array(
   'name' => 'Eric'
));
```

As, for your select, you need to tell it what table to select from.

Use either the `from` method:

```
$this->db->from('property');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$id = $this->db->get();
```

or pass `get` a table as a parameter:

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$id = $this->db->get('property');
```

Also, note that `get()` returns a query object.  You need to use `->row` (or `->result`) to get the data.

```
$this->db->from('property');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get();
$id = $query->row()->id;
```